# IE11 WebSocket object onopen: object expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I'm working in a chatsystem using websockets. Soon I realised it didn't work well in IE11 and Edge. So I've started working on a seperate JS file for those browsers using ES2015 instead of ES2016. Unfortunetely IE11 keeps bugging me like crazy!

I'm getting an Object Expected error on `Socket.onopen` in the following code:

```
function Chat(){
    /* Settings */
    this.serverHost = window.location.host;
    this.serverPort = 9300;
    this.socket = false;
}

Chat.prototype.connect = function(){
    var Socket = new WebSocket('wss://'+this.serverHost+'/myws/');
    this.setSocketEvents(Socket);
    this.socket = Socket;
}

Chat.prototype.setSocketEvents = function(Socket){
    Socket.onopen(function() { // Object expected error
        // some code..
    });
}
```

Console log: Socket

```
{binaryType: "blob", bufferedAmount: 0, CLOSED: 3, CLOSING: 2, CONNECTING: 0, extensions: "", onclose: null, onerror: null, onmessage: null, onopen: null, OPEN: 1, protocol: "", readyState: 0, url: "wss://mywebsite..."}
```

Console log: typeof(Socket)

```
object
```

I'm pretty much lost here. Anyone able to tell me what's going on?

Comment: _"So I've started working on a seperate JS file for those browsers using ES2015 instead of ES2016"_ - you can always transpile your ES2016 code to a lower version for older browsers

Comment: Wait.. I think I just realised IE11 probably needs `Socket.onopen = function(){` instead..

Comment: @JamesThorpe Thank you very much! That actually saved me a lot of trouble!